# How to add ".com" button to the keyboard with InputField widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need the device keyboard to show `[.com]` option when the InputField opens the keyboard.

I tried with TextInputType.url/emailAddress/text but they only show the `[.]` option.

[image]

I am wondering is there a solution to show `[.com]` option as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the behavior on iOS for `TextInputType.url`:

[image]

Unfortunately, I think the behavior on android for `TextInputType.url` is to show the default one:

[image]

I don't think you can change this behavior for Android. Also, users are used to it.

Comment: inputType="email" provides the ".com" button in the keyboard in Android, it can be used  as an alternative